# jmeter load test getting dynamic values from array variable

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want handle the following url parameter dynamically in jmeter load testing

```
filters=%7B%22TIME_PERIOD_TYPE%22:%5B%22QTD%22%5D,%22COUNTRY%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22TERRITORY%22:%5B%22PTPT_SL_FE_N_T01%22%5D,%22ACCOUNT_BRICK%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22OVERALL_PRIORITY%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22PRODUCT_PRIORITY_PRODUCT%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22ACCOUNT_SPECIALTY%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22ACCOUNT_TARGET_TYPE%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22ACCOUNT_VISITABLE_TYPE%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22ACCOUNT_SUB_TYPE%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22HCO_SUB_TYPE%22:%5B%22%22%5D,%22ACCOUNT_MARKET_SEGMENT%22:%5B%22%22%5D%7D
```

Here are Jmeter sampler for filtering the value
[image]

How can I handle those values dynamically using corelation? Filter value can vary for menus
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The options are in:

1. Correlate all the values one by one using the suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Get all [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) names/values from the previous response using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) and populate them in the next request using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language.
3. Use a 3rd-party recording tool like [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder), it's capable of exporting recorded requests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters, see [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details

Comment: Yes Problem is that I have to trigger from non gui mode for 100 users which will be in csv file. 2 point seems little easy than others. It seems